# What are some good strategies against land takeovers in Alexandros?

Tags: alexandros

I recently purchased [Alexandros](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8273/alexandros) and after a few games I found that getting a head start makes you the primary target for land-takeovers. A slow start can also cost you the game, however, and make it very difficult to catch up.

Being targeted for land takeover twice can leave you trailing so badly that it's impossible to come back. Usually, the player in second place benefits the most.

Are there any strategies to mitigate this?

Comment: Also, does the game depend on chance or hidden info, or is it completely open.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never played Alexandros, but have read the rules and examined the board.

Try to be the player in second place during the early and mid-game. This is known as the bicycle race strategy. Occupy small to medium value provinces. Spend turns collecting cards to position yourself to occupy a high value province while appearing to just be coasting. To keep the leader from getting too much of a lead, break up his provinces with Alexander.

Let another player grab a province from the leader first. With any luck, they'll use their excess cards fighting trading land grabs. Then us all those cards you've been accumulating to grab a big province and levy taxes.